# Resize image file (JPEG) in Smalltalk (Pharo)

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I am trying to resize an image file on my hard drive with pharo. This is my current way of doing it:

```
img := ImageReadWriter formFromFileNamed: 'picture.jpg'.
scaledimage := img scaledIntoFormOfSize: 100.
scaledimage writeJPEGfileNamed: 'scaledPicture.jpg'.
```

Is this a good way to do it? Also is there a way to specify the jpeg compression quality for this image?

Thanks!

Henne

Comment: There seems to be a magnify:by: method in the Form class as well. What I do not quite understand is why this method takes a rectangle as one of the arguments. But maybe this one is a possibility, too!?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the way to do this and wanted to share my solution. Here is the code:

```
img := ImageReadWriter formFromFileNamed: 'pic.jpg'.
scaledimage := img magnifyBy: 0.8.
PluginBasedJPEGReadWriter
  putForm: scaledimage
  quality: 95
  progressiveJPEG: false
  onFileNamed: 'scaledPicture95.jpg'.
scaledimage writeJPEGfileNamed: 'scaledPictureDfl.jpg'.
```

This way you can scale an image by a factor, in this case 0.8. Factors greater than 1 also work. Furthermore, you can specify the JPEG quality. I chose 95 in this example. The flag progressive JPEG can create an image, which shows up in a preview quality in a browser when loading and gets better the more data is transmitted. This is not supported by all browsers though! The last line is optional and just saves a second JPEG with default settings as a comparison. I hope this might help some people looking for this in the future.

Henne

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about `PluginBasedJPEGReadWriter`.

There's [Smagick](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/announcements/2007-August/000086.html). It needs ImageMagick and OSProcess to make it work though.

It can be useful if you need a complete image manipulation library.